# Load Images in Picasso from Json

Tags: android, json, gridview, imageview, picasso

Hi I Want to **Use Json To Load Images In Picasso** Library how can i achieve that? I searched many times but the tutorials I found was either with Local images Or Use URL Inside the Code ***NOT JSON*** Please Help!

here is my Code But it uses local images :

MainActivity (images Load In **GridView**)

```
import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
        import android.widget.GridView;
        import android.widget.ImageView;

        import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityTwo.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    //    our custom adapter
    private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
//            check to see if we have a view
            if (convertView == null) {
//                no view - so create a new one
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            } else {
//                use the recycled view object
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

//            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).setDebugging(true);
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                    .load(mThumbIds[position])
                    .placeholder(R.raw.place_holder)
                    .error(R.raw.big_problem)
                    .noFade().resize(150, 150)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(imageView);
            return imageView;
        }
    }

    static Integer[] mThumbIds = {R.raw.amazed, R.raw.angelic,
            R.raw.cool, R.raw.crying, R.raw.devil,
            R.raw.laughing, R.raw.loving, R.raw.question,
            R.raw.sad, R.raw.silence, R.raw.simple, R.raw.sleeping,
            R.raw.smiling, R.raw.tongue, R.raw.winking, R.raw.worried,
            R.raw.amazed, R.raw.angelic, R.raw.cool, R.raw.crying,
            R.raw.devil, R.raw.laughing, R.raw.loving, R.raw.question,
            R.raw.sad, R.raw.silence, R.raw.simple, R.raw.sleeping,
            R.raw.smiling, R.raw.tongue, R.raw.winking, R.raw.worried};
}
```

when An Image Clicked **ActivityTwo** Process the Request And Load Clicked Image In A **ImageView**
here is the code :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class ActivityTwo extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", -1);
        if (position != -1) {
            Picasso.with(ActivityTwo.this)
                    .load(MainActivity.mThumbIds[position])
                    .placeholder(R.raw.place_holder)
                    .noFade()
                    .resize(800, 800)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .error(R.raw.big_problem)
                    .into(imageView);
        } else {
            Picasso.with(ActivityTwo.this)
                    .load(R.raw.big_problem)
                    .noFade()
                    .resize(800, 800)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to android Please If you can Write a code to solve this problem tell me where i should put that

Comment: Your json probably contain the URL of the image. Parse the json and get the URL so you can give it to Picasso

Comment: show us the structure of the json so that we could help you parse into a url

Comment: @MirianaItani Here is my json structure would you help me? `{ "Assassins": [ { "link": "www.apadanadev.ir/development/game_wallpaper/img/1385140.jpg" } }, { "link": "www.apadanadev.ir/development/game_wallpaper/img/1403485.jpg" } }, { "link":"www.apadanadev.ir/development/game_wallpaper/img/1480444.jpg" } } ] } `

Comment: @DEON please check my answer and let me know if you need any help or if something is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Now here is what you do:

```
{ "Assassins": [ { "link": "www.apadanadev.ir/development/game_wallpaper/img/1385140.jpg" } }, { "link": "www.apadanadev.ir/development/game_wallpaper/img/1403485.jpg" } }, { "link":"www.apadanadev.ir/development/game_wallpaper/img/1480444.jpg" } } ] }
```

You have a jsonarray of json objects: 
Let us say the name of the array urlArray :

```
List<String> urls= new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<urlArray.length();i++){
try{
    JSONObject o = urlArray.getJSONObject(i);
    urls.add(o.get("link").toString);
 }
   catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Then you return the urls and here you have a list of Strings that you could pass to the adapter. 
In the adapter you pass them to Picasso

Comment: Thank you but where I should your code? I just copy/paste your code but "urlArray" is red! Does your code parse json? where I put My Json link? I'm new to Android and I Don't know anything about JSON Would you please Help me? Would you please Give me Complete Code?

Comment: @MirianaIteni How Can I Return Urls to adapter And Picasso?